# string concatenation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation

I have a `tf.string` tensor, `chars`, with shape `chars[Batch][None]` where `None` denotes a dynamic shaped tensor (output from a variable length sequence).

If this tensor's shape were known (e.g. `chars[Batch][Time]`), then I could achieve concatenation of strings along the last dimension as:

```
chars = tf.split(chars,chars.shape[-1],axis=-1)
words = tf.squeeze(tf.strings.join(chars))
```

However, since the shape is unknown until runtime, I cannot use `split`.

Is there another way to accomplish this for a dynamic shaped `string` tensor?

In other words, I would like the string analogy of

```
words = tf.reduce_sum(chars,axis=-1)
```

along a dynamic shaped dimension.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 23/07/2022:** Now you can use [`tf.strings.reduce_join`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/reduce_join) to join all strings into a single string, or joins along an axis

```py
words = tf.strings.reduce_join(chars, axis=-1)
```

---

This can be accomplished via:

```
words = tf.reduce_join(chars,axis=-1)
```